# Attaching a jQuery click event to a tr element but still have anchor tags in the row

Tags: jquery

I have a table that I want to add a click event to the tr elements.  I have managed to do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').live('click', function() {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

However I have anchor tags within some of the td elemets of the row that I don't want the click event to fire for, and just have their default behavior.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').live('click', function(event) {
        if($(event.target).is('a')){
            return true;
        }
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Here you are returning true if the click was on a link, and this will make the browser perform the default action for the link. If you would return false, then the default behaviour would be prevented, and thus clicking on a link would have no effect.

Comment: Yeah, I think everyone else is getting this backwards. +1

Comment: Totally right - I changed the code appropriately.  Right answer!

Answer (score 2):

Have your event listener receive a variable 'e', which will be the click event, and check

```
if($(e.target).is('a'))
   return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 $('tr').not('a').live('click', function() {
```

Comment: That selector gives you "all tr-elements that are not a-elements", which is really just a weird way of selecting "all tr-elements"

Answer (score 1):

Should anybody, like myself, happen to have any tag inside the `<a>`, such as `<i>` or `<span>`, the following condition will match the click not only in the `a` area, but also in its children:

```
$('tr').live('click', function(e) {
  var jqTarget = $(e.target);
  if (jqTarget.closest("a", jqTarget.closest("tr")[0]).length === 0) {
    // event handler
  }
}
```

The explanation is: `closest(selector, context)` will return the first parent element (including self) that matches `selector` inside the `context` element ([docs here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)). Is this returns an element, then the click was made on a anchor or on one of its children.

Comment: Why not use this instead of searching the closest tr? I implemented your idea like this: `if (jqTarget.closest('a', this).length > 0) return true;`. And then of course implement the event handler beyond that if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You need to stop propagation on the anchor elements. This can be done very easily with jquery. See my example below. This code should be in a $(document).ready block.

```
// Do not propage clicks on deadZone class
$('.deadZone').click( function(e){              
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Then on the anchor tags you would add a class = deadZone.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign click events to those anchors and set the click function to return false.  This prevents the click event from bubbling past the anchor tags.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr a').live('click', function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```